# Google Chrome on Windows 10 doesn't remember window size on close/reopen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I like to set the Chrome browser window to maximum vertical height and manually set width. However, after closing and reopening Chrome, the browser window is no longer in the position and size I set. I get the same resize behavior if I leave the browser window open, switch the PC to a second user and then back again to my user. This resizing problem seems to be unique to Chrome. Microsoft Edge and other browsers I've tried don't have this problem. I've tried closing Chrome while holding Ctrl and/or Shift keys - no help. Any ideas?

Comment: I did a test in my windows 10 PC. But I got the same resize behavior after closing the Chrome and reopening it. Or may be you can try to resize the window, then right click the tab and choose "size" and click the window. After you close and reopen it, you should get a resized window.

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, more of a workaround with third party help, I use a programme called shellfolderfix, it uses very few resources and remembers all the sizes and positions of all the browser and programme windows that windows uses. works with MS Office too.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how you can fix this problem.

***What I was trying, which didn't work*:**

1. open new Google Chrome window (CTRL+N)
2. resize this new window
3. close this window
4. open again a new window (CTRL+N) and test its size

***What proved to be the correct sequence:***

1. resize EVERY opened Google Chrome window (including maximized ones)
2. open a new window (CTRL+N) and test its size

Therefore it looks like new Google Chrome windows get the size of the one that "generated" them. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking the header to bring it to full screen does not work, BUT
Dragging it up into the corner until it gives you the full screen outline does.
Once you do that, close it and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

What I found on my machine, was even though the windows for Chrome were closed, Task Manager still showed it running.

Ending the task. Opening Chrome again, resizing, closing, then opening one more time and it was at the correct resize.

Top corner X seems to not kill the program completely.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution: **PersistentWindows** this little gem of a program has saved me hours by not having to resize all my windows every time I turn off my monitor.
First tried:
**ShellFolderFix** was too old(WIN7) and
**WinSize2** would not install properly for me.
Very easy to use -thank you whomever!